# Hbase connection problems and failed to create table

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hbase, apache-zookeeper, nosql

I'm running a multi-node cluster; I'm using hadoop-1.0.3(on both), Hbase-0.94.2(on both) and zookeeper-3.4.6(only master)

master:192.168.0.1
slave:192.168.0.2

Hbase is not running perfectly and I faced problems while trying to create a table on hbase
and of course I can't access HBase status UI on `http://master:60010` please Help!!

Here is all my configuration files :

(hadoop conf) core-site.xml: (same configuration on both master and slave)

```
 <configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

(hbase conf) hbase-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://master:54310/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>master,slave</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2222</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts and :

```
192.168.0.1 master
192.168.0.2 slave
```

regionservers:

```
master
slave
```

here is the log file : hbase-hduser-regionserver-master.log

```
2014-12-24 02:12:13,190 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:286)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1035)
2014-12-24 02:12:14,002 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server master/192.168.0.1:2181
2014-12-24 02:12:14,003 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will not SASL-authenticate because the default JAAS configuration section 'Client' could not be found. If you are not using SASL, you may ignore this. On the other hand, if you expected SASL to work, please fix your JAAS configuration.
2014-12-24 02:12:14,004 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to master/192.168.0.1:2181, initiating session
2014-12-24 02:12:14,005 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2014-12-24 02:12:14,675 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping server on 60020
2014-12-24 02:12:14,676 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: ABORTING region server master,60020,1419415915643: Initialization of RS failed.  Hence aborting RS.
java.io.IOException: Received the shutdown message while waiting.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.blockAndCheckIfStopped(HRegionServer.java:623)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeZooKeeper(HRegionServer.java:598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.preRegistrationInitialization(HRegionServer.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:669)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-12-24 02:12:14,676 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
2014-12-24 02:12:14,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Initialization of RS failed.  Hence aborting RS.
2014-12-24 02:12:14,683 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Registered RegionServer MXBean
2014-12-24 02:12:14,689 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook starting; hbase.shutdown.hook=true; fsShutdownHook=Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
2014-12-24 02:12:14,689 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Shutdown hook
2014-12-24 02:12:14,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook: Starting fs shutdown hook thread.
2014-12-24 02:12:14,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook finished.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead `localhost` in `core-site.xml` file use `master`.

And add slave nodes hosts to `slave` file in hadoop directory.

And both master & slave nodes `core-site.xml` file look like this:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:54310</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

master and slave hosts should be present in both regionservers file if you make present zookeeper in both.

Comment: you can format namenode if you want, but you  will lose all your hdfs saved data.